# Pandas select rows by index then append

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dir = 'data_r14.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data_dir)
# print(data)

signals = data['signal']

value_counts = signals.value_counts()

buy_count = value_counts[1]

signals_code = [1, 2]
buy_sell_rows = data.loc[data['signal'].isin(signals_code)]


data_without_signals = data[~data['signal'].isin(signals_code)]
random_0_indexes = np.random.choice(data_without_signals.index.values, buy_count)
value_counts2 = data_without_signals['signal'].value_counts()

# print(value_counts2)

for index in random_0_indexes:
    row = data.loc[index, :]
    # df = row.to_frame()
    print(row)
    buy_sell_rows.append(row)
    # print(buy_sell_rows)
    # print(signals.loc[index, :])
# print(random_0_rows)

print(buy_sell_rows)

# print(buy_sell_rows['signal'].value_counts())
```

So I have a dataframe where I have a column named `signal` where the values are either 0, 1, or 2 and I want to balance them by having equal amount rows for each value because they are very unbalanced I have only 1984 row of non zero value and over 20000 rows of zero value.

So I created a new dataframe where all the values are zeroes and called it `data_without_signals` then I get a random list of indexes from it, then I run a loop to get that `row` to append it to another dataframe I created called `buy_sell_rows` where only non zero values are in, but the issue is that `row` is being appened.

Comment: `.append()` is not working inplace. It create a new df. You need to `buy_sell_rows = buy_sell_rows.append(row)`

Comment: @Racooneer OMG I didn't have my coffee yet, thank you so much.

Comment: `loc` can take a list of indeces. Something like `buy_sell_rows = data.loc[random_0_indexes, :]` should be able to create the frame directly without the `for`. No?

Comment: @KadiemAlqazzaz I'm pretty sure, there is a better way overall using Pandas `.sample()` function where you sample the same n form all groups of "signal" using length of  the smallest group (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment, I think your general approach could be simplified by randomly sampling the different signals:

```
# my test signal of 0s, 1s and 2s
test = pd.DataFrame({"data" : [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]})

# get the lowest size of any group, which is the size all groups should be reduced to
max_size = test.groupby("data")["data"].count().min()

# sample
output = (test
    .groupby(["data"])
    .agg(sample = ("data", lambda x : x.sample(max_size).to_list()))
    .explode("sample")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

and the output for this test is:

|  | sample |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |